# CLS issue only for PageSpeed Insights

Tags: google, page-speed, lighthouse

Hi get a 99 score in lighthouse and also in PageSpeed Insights BUT PageSpeed Insights gives me ( for desktop ) a FAIL because it thinks I have a 0,67 CLS issue

I did test it with GTmetrix, webvitals Debugger, CLS extension and all of them give me a GOOD score almost no CLS is recorded

the problem is that inside Search -> web vitals ( desktop ) console pages are marked in red with POOR because a CLS issue

Any idea on hot to debug and fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details, it is hard to be exact.  The usual culprits of CLS are

- Delayed loading of images and videos and they don't have the size specified
- Slow loading of Fonts
- Dynamic content added by javascript
- Layout changed by CSS and javascript